# Meteor Autoform afQuickField: How to omit title / help-area?

Tags: forms, meteor

I am using the awesome aldeed/meteor-autoform package.

How can I omit the title label (e.g. "Month") and the help area (e.g. "Month required) when using afQuickField?

I need some fields without title and some without help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the **label** of the field as defined from your schema. If you want the label to be omitted you can try using a single space, like the following:

```
Schema = {};
Schema.contact = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: " ",
    max: 50
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say *"help area"*.  Would you please provide an example?